# Android: How to Disable "Icon Frames" on my application's launcher icon?

Tags: android, icons

I want to remove "icon frames" in my application launcher icon.
In below image I didn't turn on "icon frames" in settings.

[image]

When I turn on "icon frames" in setting this image change like below.

[image]

As you see Telegram icon didn't change. How to make launcher icon like telegram's icon. Never change no matter "icon frames" is turn on or turn off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find answer for my question.

just add below code to Manifest.xml file:

```
<application>
<meta-data   
     android:name="com.samsung.android.icon_container.has_icon_container" 
     android:value="true"/>
</application>
```